# Mongodb data finding

Tags: python, mongodb

I want it to start from the last part in the data and get the correct data to the beginning, please help me

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    db = db_client['Data1']
    db1 = db[f'test']
    db2 = db1.find()

    for x in db2:
        await ctx.guild.create_role(name=x['name'])
```